# Deploy to Production - Cancel Deploy After Test Failure

Tags: deployment, migration-tool

I am using the [Ant Migration Tool](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Migration_Tool_Guide) for deployments. While utilizing this tool, all deployments are visible under the [Monitor Deployments](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/changesets_monitor_deployment.htm) page. In a client's production instance, they have more than 1200 unit tests currently written. As the tests run, it will tell you if there are any failures or not. These tests take about 45mins to run all the way through. If I see an error in test 100, I would love to just exit out, fix it, and try deploying again rather than waiting the full 45mins for that one error.

So, I don't think this is possible, but can I cancel out of a deploy once I start it?

Comment: There's an idea here: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YJPNAA4, so it doesn't look promising...wonder if someone has a clever way of handling it.

Comment: I voted for that idea.

Comment: I voted for the idea as well. Thanks Peter. This is not a very nice "feature" in my opinion. If you know you have a failure, just stop deploying and tell the developer to fix it.

Comment: @PeterKnolle I would say, based on the feedback provided below and your comment, that this isn't available yet. If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it. Hopefully that can get the Idea more visibility.

Comment: When using ANT, you can execute every test class individually instead of running "All Tests". So you could have a 'test' task that tests every test class and halts once a test returns a failure and you wouldn't have to wait for all the tests to run.

Comment: @PepeFloyd You can test a single class as part of a deploy and fail after only that test? As far as I know, the `runTests` parameter is ignored when going to production - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_deploying_ant_deploy.htm - Is the documentation incorrect or are you referencing something different? You have me very interested!

Comment: Check out the Summer 13 Release Notes, page 231 - https://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_summer13_release_notes.pdf

Comment: That is awesome! Thanks @MikeChale for pointing that out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not currently possible to cancel a deployment; however, there is a [Cancel Deployment idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YJPNAA4) on the Idea Exchange.  Vote for it!

Comment: It looks like this is coming in Summer '13. In the Release Notes (https://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_summer13_release_notes.pdf), page 231, under Metadata API: Metadata deployments can be canceled while in progress.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** In hindsight, this doesn't seem like a very good idea and is likely unworkable. I'll leave it here in case someone can salvage it or to at least stop them going down the same path.

---

The idea suggested by Peter in the comments is worth promoting as a native solution provided by Salesforce is probably the only clean solution.

As a more custom solution, how about creating a base class that all unit tests inherit from that would allow you to bypass subsequent tests after the first failure? Something like having a static member on the test class that tracks if there has been a failure. Then check this value at the start of each test to see if it should be run to completion.

I know this isn't ideal as it would require you to modify your existing tests to first check if there was already a failure. Also, it won't address any external managed package tests and won't work between classes.

Actually, the more I think it through the less appealing this idea is. You would need to move all your assertions into the base class so that it could set the static member before potentially failing the actual assertion. Which would muck up the stack traces etc...

Comment: Well, external managed package tests don't run during a deploy so I am not worried about them. However, I agree that this really isn't very ideal and I don't think it would work correctly (considering I need to mark each class as @isTest which forces the tests to run). Thanks for the idea though! +1!

Comment: Statics variables are reset between test runs.

Comment: To achieve this kind of inter-test communication, you could manually (not from the code) set a checkbox value on your User record (User object wouldn't need to violate SeeAllData) in your target org when you see that the deployment is reporting a failed test and set up your tests so the first thing they do is check for it and fail if necessary.  Or, maybe you could come up with something clever with auto-numbers knowing that their increments live on outside of their tests. Nothing seems too clean, though.

Comment: Yeah, I pretty much had to abandon the idea once I realized there wasn't an easy way to communicate between the tests.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but may address the issue of dealing with deployments to orgs with LOTS of tests.  Once an org has that many tests it starts to cause a bunch of pain with deployment and people stop working to create as many tests (at least in my experience).

What I've been looking to try is instead of hosting all the tests in Salesforce, only tests required to maintain code coverage are hosted natively.  The rest our hosted in an external repository.  Then an automated process checks out the tests and runs them on a scheduled basis.  Alternatively, the tests are present in Salesforce but commented out with a flag that would allow an automated script to uncomment and run the test on a scheduled basis.  The idea is that you can creates lots of tests without worrying about speed, but still maintain fast performance.

Comment: This isn't a bad idea if you are doing development in your own org, but for developing in a client org this doesn't seem viable. We can't just store their tests in different locations. We also can only control what goes on in production to a certain extent (Admins can make whatever changes they want straight in prod for instance). Having all of the tests in prod allow us to know when a new workflow rule/validation rule was introduced that broke our tests. I'm also not really sure how you can check out tests and run them without putting them on an org. Thanks for the idea though! +1!

Comment: IMHO, admins don't run all tests when they make changes.  Since this would be a scheduled process it would catch those sort of tests failures quicker (as opposed to waiting until you deploy to find out an admin has broken your test).  To run the tests without putting them in the org we'd just be doing a validation only deployment (most likely with ANT which also has convenient tasks for the checkout feature)